# How can adhoc commands be run on sets of hosts? (e.g. hosts in group 1 AND group 2, hosts in group 1 and NOT group 2, etc)

Tags: ansible

Given the below `inventory` file, how can adhoc commands such as `ansible -m raw -a 'mkdir test'` be run on different sets of the machines?

For example, how can the command be run on:

- hosts which are in `app1` AND `app2`
- hosts which are in `app1` and NOT in `app2`
- hosts which are in `app1` OR `app2`

Here is the inventory file:

```
[app1]
ip1.address
ip2.address
ip3.address

[app2]
ip1.address
ip2.address
ip4.address
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run Ansible ad-hoc on different host groups as stated in your question. The -l parameter known as limit, is used to execute your tasks on a limited set of nodes in the inventory.

- hosts which are in app1 AND app2

> ansible all -i '/path/to/inventory' -l 'app1,app2' -m shell -a "mkdir
>   $HOME/test"

- hosts which are in app1 and NOT in app2

> ansible all -i '/path/to/inventory' -l 'app1' -m shell -a "mkdir
>   $HOME/test"

- hosts which are in app1 OR app2

> ansible all -i '/path/to/inventory' -l 'app1:app2' -m shell -a "mkdir
>   $HOME/test

PS: The path to inventory need not be explicitly specified, if it has been already configured in ansible.cfg to be the inventory.

Comment: How does `ansible all -l 'app1' -m shell -a "mkdir $HOME/test"` exclude `app2`?

Comment: because, you limit the play to run only on app1, using the  -l (limit) paramete.

Comment: Using the example inventory file, how would limiting to `app1` prevent running the commands on `ip1.address` and `ip2.address`?

Comment: oops, I did not see the hosts inside the group, i was answering only on the group level. But what you could do is make ip1 and ip2 to be a common group. ip3 to another group, ip4 to another group. And then target the hosts

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question now, but you can also do:

```
ansible all -i '/path/to/inventory' -l '!app2' -m shell -a "mkdir $HOME/test"
```

which will run on all hosts in the inventory that are not in app2. Or, if your inventory contains more than the two groups shown, and you want to limit to hosts in app1 and not app2:

```
ansible app1 -i '/path/to/inventory' -l '!app2' -m shell -a "mkdir $HOME/test"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can find all about it here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html

```
Description             Pattern(s)                  Targets
All hosts               all (or *)   
One host                host1    
Multiple hosts          host1:host2 (or host1,host2)     
One group               webservers   
Multiple groups         webservers:dbservers        all hosts in webservers plus all hosts in dbservers
Excluding groups        webservers:!atlanta         all hosts in webservers except those in atlanta
Intersection of groups  webservers:&staging         any hosts in webservers that are also in staging
```